# socket.io upgrade from 0.6 to 0.7 causes problems in socket.request

Tags: javascript, cookies, node.js, http-headers, socket.io

I had an application that uses node.js and socket.io. It was working fine three months ago but when I tried to run it now it showed me that **the module socket.io is not defined (don't know why?)**. So I installed it again using `npm install socket.io`. It turned out that socket.io new version was released with a different set of functions (or at least the way it is used). I fixed the changes but have still some problem. Here is what I do:

**server:**

```
    var http = require('http');
    ...
    var server = http.createServer ( function (request,response){
            console.log("Client request: " + request.url);
            ...
    });

    server.listen(port);

    var socketOptions = {
            transportOptions: {
                    'xhr-polling': {
                            closeTimeout: 12000000, //20 mins
                            timeout: 1200000  //20 mins
                    }
            }
    }

    var io = require('socket.io').listen(server,socketOptions);

    io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket) {
            console.log("WebSocket client connected");

            if (!socket.request) { // xhr polling => get cookie using websocket message
                    socket.json.send(JSON.stringify({
                            message: "resendcookie",
                            why: "Missing cookie",
                    }));
            } else {
                    console.dir(socket.request.headers.cookie);

                    ... <use the cookie> ...

            }

            io.sockets.on ("message", function(data) {
                    ...
            });

            io.sockets.on("close", function(){
                    ...
            });

            io.sockets.on("disconnect", function(){
                    ...
            });
    });
```

**client:**

```
    var socket = io.connect("localhost:port", {
            rememberTransport   :  false,
            transportOptions    : {
                    "xhr-polling": {
                            closeTimeout: 600000,
                            duration: 600000
                    }
            }
    });

    ...

    function onload() {
            ...

            socket.on("connect", function(){
                    ...
            }

            socket.on("mesasge", function(data) {

                    var m =JSON.parse(data);
                    if (m.message === "resendcookie"){
                            socket.send(JSON.stringify({
                                    cookie: document.cookie,
                            }));
                    }
            });
    }
```

This is a slightly modified code of what was working fine with socket.io 0.6 to include the new way to connect and listen to the websocket. My problem is:

socket.request used to exist if using chrome since it allows for websockets and I could reach the cookies directly (the xhr-polling trick I used to reach cookies in other browsers that don't support websockets). **Now socket.request is giving different results even with chrome and I can't find the cookies**. Did I forget to modify anything else? If not, please me tell how to reach the cookies.

Thanks a lot,

Sabah

Answer (score 1):

Did you read https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Migrating-0.6-to-0.7 ?
It contains allot of information on migrating from 0.6 to the latest 0.7

Comment: thanks @3rdEden for your reply. Actually I used this page for migration and it helped a lot in establishing the connection and sending messages between client and server. In v0.7, the socket parameter sent to the server when a client connects is different and it doesn't contain the http request containing the cookie anymore. **So my problem is how can I read the cookies?**

Comment: We removed socket.request because it was unreliable, in 0.7 we introduced `socket.handshake` that contains information about the user that we gathered during the handshaking process. You can find headers, ip's etc in this property. See related wiki: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing